# Could a jet style flame holder help a Raptor relight during its landing manuver?

Tags: spacex

After reviewing the split second ignition of the 3 Starship SN 9 Raptor engines on their successful liftoff and ascent on video, thoughts began to focus on their relight issues during the "seven seconds of terror" Hoverslam landing technique.

Specifically, during a launch, the engines are static and upright. Gaseous methane, lighter than air, will accumulate near the top of the combustion chamber.

However, during the landing maneuver, the Raptor nozzle is in the equivalent of a Category 5 hurricane airstream.  This would seem to potentially cause a great deal of unstable, turbulent airflow around the nozzle, and act as a vacuum aspirator, pulling the fuel air mixture out before sustained ignition can be achieved.

Jets solve this issue by protecting the flame with a "can".  Could it help the Raptor to "keep a pilot light on" using can(s) to ensure reliable ignition for their powered landings?

Comment: I think the ignition methods are radically different in rocket engines.

Comment: The Raptor's restart problems are not due to ignition difficulties, but to plumbing. The incorrect amounts of methane and oxygen arriving at the combustion chamber.

Comment: @PcMan which extreme turbulence and unpredictable air flow would only exacerbate.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni um, NO. If your turbulence and airflow is affecting your mass flow rate through your turbopumps, you have WAY bigger problems than just ignition!!!

Comment: @PcMan um, it would not affect the mass flow rate, but could affect their ratio in the ignition area.  A relight in a 200 mph *crosswind* should be tested.  Head on will be better because the fuel and oxygen are being rammed back into the nozzle.  But, yes, certainly, the flow rates must be good.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni The primary ignition is done in the turbopump preburners. If those are exposed in any way to the conditions outside, something catastrophically bad has already happened and you are looking at a pile of scrap, not an engine. Once the preburners are ignited, you have hot gas blasting out of the injectors at pressures, temperatures, and flow rates that completely outclass a category 5 hurricane, and that's before combustion of the two gas streams with each other starts. Airflow that could prevent engine startup would most likely rip the vehicle apart.

Answer (score 5):

The problem wasn't the ignition mechanism - that's done with a sparking system.  The problem (appeared) to be the fuel supply to the engine.  You could see it was attempting to relight (and successfully lit a few times), but appeared to not be getting the stable fuel supply to maintain the flame.  A can can't help with that.

The biggest problem with spinning around to land is it's a massive dynamic change which means liquids move all over the place when you do it, in both the tanks and the pipes.  Getting that stable enough to light every time is... problematic, hard and awesome that SpaceX is trying.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that liquids slosh in the pipes? I would be surprised if there are voids in the feedlines. A reference would be great.

Comment: For Starship specifically, no.  Just covering all bases for a safety critical moment in flight.  In general though, Pogo Oscillation is a type of liquids sloshing in pipes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pogo_oscillation.

Comment: No, that's not what pogo is at all. Slosh occurs at a liquid/vapor boundary. BTW Raptor doesn't use chemical igniters. You might want to give your answer a tune up and stick to what can be proven or at least clearly state where you're guessing.

Comment: Fair call.  I was pretty loose on "slosh" - was more meaning to talk about chaotic movement than the actual physics of "Slosh Dynamics".  Wild changes in local "gravity" causes liquids to move all over the place is more what I was getting at.  I didn't feel the OP wanted a full physical treatment, so I kept it pretty loose.

Comment: @throx the header tanks (really a second stage tankage feeding the same engines to land (instead of continuing on into space)) is designed to handle "slosh" (maybe not entirely suceessfully).  The air turbulence around the Raptor nozzles may lower the odds even further, which is why it has been proposed to get it **vertical and stable** with a drouge 'chute, which would also give the nozzles a much more predictable and reliable *ram* air flow (if only to keep the fuel/lox in its chamber to relight).

Comment: @throx (and others) read up on "ullage" motors, and why they are needed for re-lights in space. (the drag device will help do the same thing for a landing).

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni You mean *you* have proposed parachutes. As explained to you before, they're not a solution to any problem Starship has. There's no reason to think the relight failure was due to orientation or airflow, the three successful engine relights between the two test flights serve as counterexamples to the idea. The cause has not been publicly mentioned, but the fact that they're implementing redundant engine ignition in response indicates it was likely an engine problem.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff  sorry, 2 crashes are enough example for me.  And, for early flights, a parachute gives you *more* of a chance for a successful relight.  Remember, they need to do other things, like examine the effect of the airflow on the fins.  As much of your writings are good, I don't care to argue, but please keep an open mind. (They need to get one back whole). Parachutes will be greatly helpful on Mars.  And you have erroneously stated that supersonic parachutes won't work.  Let's leave this open for now.

Comment: Neither of those crashes would have been helped by a parachute. SN9's second engine clearly wasn't going to relight successfully, and even a late relight wouldn't have avoided the problem of only having one engine when it was attempting the flip maneuver. It needed the three-engine redundancy to be implemented, not a parachute. SN8 actually perfectly executed the maneuver you're trying to "fix", it only ran into trouble when it got to the single-engine landing part of the burn with its landing engine consuming itself due to low fuel pressure. Parachutes would have been completely useless.

Comment: Parachutes are complex, heavy, failure prone, scale poorly (which is why previous landers have been so size-limited), and are incompatible with precision landings. Supersonic parachutes are another order of magnitude more complex, which is why ExoMars isn't landing this year: they haven't been able to get a supersonic parachute working reliably while just trying to land a simple reentry vehicle massing a few hundred kilograms. There are many reasons why parachutes are not suitable for Starship, and it's been discussed in great detail, which is why I keep telling you to go do some research.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni If you have another question like "Why doesn't Starship use parachutes", then I suggest you ask it so other people can find it (assuming it's not already there).  Comments aren't for followup questions.

Comment: Well, certainly hoping SN 10 does better, not ruling out chutes just yet, especially for Martian model.

Comment: "not ruling out chutes just yet": SpaceX already did that. Even ten years ago they'd determined that Red Dragon would require major vehicle redesigns to allow parachute landing, and would get more payload down with higher precision and allow landing at higher altitudes if it eliminated them. It's very likely nothing larger than Curiosity or Perseverance will ever land on Mars using parachutes. Even those might be the last of their scale to do so, their complex landing systems being rendered obsolete by powered landing.

Comment: Complexity aside, chutes are not reusable, which is a core requirement for everything on Starship.

Comment: @throx they can be, unless you're unlucky (and they are easy to damage if you are). Inspection and handling for such a critical use would be extremely labor intensive though, and certainly not conducive to rapid reflight.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff Yep - one day I'll learn to not use loose language.  They're reusable in much the same way the Space Shuttle was.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Flame holder will probably not withstand temperatures inside engine.
What maybe is the reignition problem is that LOX header tank is 50m far from engines. Due to that lenght there is probably pressure and mass flow drop and therefore unproper feed of oxidiser. If they try ignite all 3 on landing i think it's gona be even worse case then SN 8&9.

Comment: They ignited two engines on SN8's flight with no oxidizer pressure issues, and despite low pressures from the fuel tank which was much closer to the engines. I figure we've seen the last of the fuel pressure issues until they go back to fully autogenous pressurization, which I expect they'll do eventually (it's likely way down on their list of priorities, since they can easily just include some helium tanks and still do almost all of their satellite launch business).